# How can I declare variables of an object to undefined

Tags: javascript, object, undefined

I dont know why but I just cant figure out how to declare items in an object but not define them. For example with a normal variable I
would just do this:

```
var example ;
```

But I cant figure out how to do this with an object.
Eg.

```
 var object = {
    1 : (UNDEFINED)
    2: (UNDEFINED)
    };
```

That wont work... 
But Im sure there is an obvious answer!

Comment: why don't you set it to `null`?

Comment: If you don't define it, it will be `undefined`, wouldn't it? `var object = {}`

Comment: `var object = {1:undefined, 2:undefined};` works.

Comment: You **don't declare** object shapes in JS at all. If you don't need the values, don't put them there.

Comment: What would be the most efficient way then?

Comment: @Manu: As John said, just do `var object = {};`. But what do you want to use this "declaration" for? Maybe there's a better solution to [your problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377)

Comment: Im using a library called p5.js and it has two variables called  mouseY and mouseX which tracks the coordinates of your mouse. I need to create lots of insances/variables with mouseY +1,+10,+20,-20 etc in an object. however mouseY can only be used in the draw() function so I need to declare it forehand, then define it with mouseY.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As John Bupit and Bergi 6 said, I dont define at all.
like this:

```
var object = {}
```

Or I could define the value to null or undefined as slash197 and Dal Hundal said.